# Efficient filtering of data with varying number of filters in Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

### Basic Issue and Architecture

I am developing a high-performance microservice in Spring Boot, that exposes an API. **I want to perform some efficient filtering based on API request, but the number of filters is varying**.

 My solution consists of 2 components - a **Spring Boot API** microservice and **SQL database (Postgres)**.

---

### Use Case Scenario

For the purpose of this question I will use a different, very simplified domain - Recipes. DB stores info such as dish name, ingredients, recipe type, cooking time, link to a video,...
Use case scenario:

1. I receive an API request from the user with 8 parameters (always with all 8 parameters), such as *recipe type*, *mobile app version*, *country*, *allergies*,...
2. I have to deliver a result, based on 1-8 parameters:

   - In **all cases, 1 parameter is important**: *recipe type*. I run a query based on these parameters and return a result to the user
   - In **some cases (and this is where I have the problem)**, additional parameters from the API request are important - so I must do **additional filtering based on these parameters**. I expect to have a few hundred (or even thousand) filters in the final solution. Example:

     - If a user is lactose intolerant, exclude recipes with milk
     - If the mobile app version is 2.0 exclude recipes that contain video (cause the app crashes)
     - If a user is from Saudi Arabia, exclude recipes with pork

So my filters cannot be directly searched for in the DB (e.g. the DB doesn't currently store any info about lactose intolerance, Saudi Arabia, or mobile app version 2.0).
Of course, **any** combination of these filters is possible (e.g. lactose intolerant user with app version 2.0).

---

### My solutions so far

I expect the list of filters to be changing quite frequently and I want to implement an efficient logic to handle this issue. **I need an approach that is fast and where new filters can be added easily**.

My ideas so far:

- **Solution 1:** Generate a basic JPA query (only with *recipe type* condition). Then check (in if statements?), if values from the request require additional filtering and add additional conditions to the basic query for every filter.
- **Solution 2:** Run the basic JPA query in all cases, then do additional filtering in Java if needed (with some if statements) - even though, according to my research, most articles say that the DB needs to do the filtering

Even though the approaches described above are ok (they do the job), I find them very naïve. What bothers me the most is the following:

1. New filters cannot be added easily - code has to be changed every time a new filter is
   added.
2. Filters are implemented as IF statements, which means that the code is not at all efficient (if there are a few hundred filters, every request needs to go through **all** IF statements)
3. The code is not easily readable.

---

### Ideas?

Does it maybe make sense to store exclusion rules in some special data structure (and how to efficiently do so)? 
Is SQL (+ Spring Data JPA) the best query language for this problem?
Is there something very obvious I am missing?

---

**Edit**

I tried with **spring-dynamic-jpa** suggested by **joutvhu** but I ran into some problems, even though I think (hope) I correctly replicated the example from README.md.

What I tried:

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = DynamicJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public interface SqlDAO extends JpaRepository<RecipeData, Long> {

@DynamicQuery(
            value = "select r from RecipeData r where r.performanceScore = :performanceScore\n" +
                    "<#if countryCode?has_content>\n" +
                    " and r.country.countryCode = :countryCode\n" +
                    "</#if>"
    )
    List<RecipeData> findByPerformanceScoreAndCountry_CountryCode(int performanceScore, String countryCode);

    // ...other code...
}
```

When the above function is called I get the same result as if there was no @DynamicQuery annotation. Any idea why this is so? I do not get any errors, everything seems to be working, just @DynamicQuery is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, filtering really should be done in DB. You have several options.

1. JPA query. Basically in your repository you can create a method

Employee findByEmplyeeNameAndAge(String name, Integer age);

where you have a table Employee with many columns including "name" and "age" and you have an entity class Employee mapped to that table. This method would search by filtering columns name and age. You can make any number of such methods. Read about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference). But this way is not good enough if you need to provide a way to filter by ANY combinations of columns. Hence the dynamic query (Second option)

2. Dynamic Queries. One of the implementations is DSL query. Read about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-querydsl) and [here](http://www.querydsl.com/). This will give you a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

[spring-dynamic-jpa](https://github.com/joutvhu/spring-dynamic-jpa), it will help you to easily implement dynamic query by write a query template.

The query template will be easier to read and add filters.

Comment: This seems very promising and exactly what I need. I tried to replicate examples from README.md on my example, but I ran into some problems. I can't figure out where I went wrong when reading through the documentation/examples provided in the repository. I added my problem into my original post, could you please give it a quick look?

Comment: First, you need to configure your project so it can work with jpa.

Then, add `repositoryFactoryBeanClass = DynamicJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class` to the EnableJpaRepositories annotation. Or add `repository-factory-bean-class="com.joutvhu.dynamic.jpa.support.DynamicJpaRepositoryFactoryBean"` to `<jpa:repositories>` tag, if you using xml for configure

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. JPA is (at least I think so) correctly configured in my project. All the Spring Data JPA queries are working fine, also the "normal" @Query annotation works without problems. Just the @DynamicQueriy is ignored. Did I understand correctly that the `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = DynamicJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class) ` annotation needs to be above the `public interface SqlDAO extends JpaRepository<PerformanceData, Long>`? (see my edit above)

Comment: You can see [example here](https://github.com/joutvhu/spring-dynamic-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/com/joutvhu/dynamic/jpa/JpaDynamicApplication.java)

Comment: The @EnableJpaRepositories annotation will be set on your config class, not repository class